# How to hide portion of padded/margin image out of div without padding/marging the main container div of image?

Tags: html, css

Suppose image contain in DIV1 and Text Contain in DIV2.
Both Div1 and Div2 are float Left.So I want to hide the padded image.
As my contents of DIV2 are dynamic, so I don't want to set height in any div.
Even box-sizing:padding-box not worked in this code or browser.
[image]
My Desire Output like as below image by cropping the Monitor stand:
[image]

```css
.monitor-area
{
 background:#ebebeb;
 height:auto;
}
.monitor-area:after
{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}

.monitor
{
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.monitor img
{
 width:100%;
}
.monitor-content
{
 width:44%;
 overflow:hidden;
 float:right;
 padding-right:2%;
}
.monitor-title
{
 margin-top:80px;
}

.monitor-title h1
{
 color:#333333;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.monitor-text
{
}
```

```html
<section  class="monitor-area">
 <div class="monitor">
 <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ioQ47Q/monitor.png" alt="448*250px" />
 </div>
 <div class="monitor-content">
  <div class="monitor-title">
  <h1>A CATCHY TITLE</h1></div>
  
  <div class="monitor-text">
  <p>Cursuspenatisaccum ut curabitur nulla tellus tor 
  ames a in curabitur pede. Idet mollisi eros dis orci 
  congue elis et curabitur consequam intesque. 
  Curabiturpisametur in ante.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="monitor-button">
  <a href="">read more 
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
  </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please explain in simple words, Its hard to understand what exactly you want

Comment: Just see two images. I expect the output like last images by hiding the bottom part of Monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.monitor-area
{
 background:#ebebeb;
 height:auto;
}
.monitor-area:after
{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}

.monitor
{
 width:50%;
 float:left;
 overflow:hidden;
max-height:205px
}
.monitor img
{
 width:100%;
}
.monitor-content
{
 width:44%;
 overflow:hidden;
 float:right;
 padding-right:2%;
}
.monitor-title
{
 margin-top:80px;
}

.monitor-title h1
{
 color:#333333;
 font-size:30px;
 font-weight:normal;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}
.monitor-text
{
}
```

```html
<section  class="monitor-area">
 <div class="monitor">
 <img src="https://image.ibb.co/ioQ47Q/monitor.png" alt="448*250px" />
 </div>
 <div class="monitor-content">
  <div class="monitor-title">
  <h1>A CATCHY TITLE</h1></div>
  
  <div class="monitor-text">
  <p>Cursuspenatisaccum ut curabitur nulla tellus tor 
  ames a in curabitur pede. Idet mollisi eros dis orci 
  congue elis et curabitur consequam intesque. 
  Curabiturpisametur in ante.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="monitor-button">
  <a href="">read more 
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
  </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```